# Support for case sensitive Windows directories in NIO.2

Tags: java, windows-subsystem-for-linux, ntfs, nio2, fsutil

Recent Windows 10 builds feature an ability to mark a single NTFS directory (**not** the whole file system) as case sensitive, via `fsutil.exe`:

- [Per-directory case sensitivity and WSL](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/per-directory-case-sensitivity-and-wsl/)
- [How to Enable Case Sensitive File and Folder Names on Windows 10](https://www.howtogeek.com/354220/how-to-enable-case-sensitive-folders-on-windows-10/)

If I want to query the case-sensitive flag of a given directory from a Java application, I'm currently left with the only option of calling

```
fsutil.exe file queryCaseSensitiveInfo ...
```

on a per-directory basis, which means spawning potentially multiple processes, which is expensive.

Are there any planned NIO.2 API extensions in newer Java versions (11+) targeted at case-sensitive NTFS and/or WSL file systems?

Comment: No, there is not, because that would be an OS-specific API, and Java is mostly OS-agnostic.

Comment: @Andreas, still, while being OS-agnostic, Java (starting with version 7) supports OS-specific `Path` implementations for UNIX and Windows and can read both POSIX and NTFS file attributes. Not to mention Windows-specific AsyncIO support.

Comment: Java on Windows handles filesystem access of files a/A in same case-sensitive dir - eg Files.readString() or Files.exists checks different case files, BUT Path manipulation does not check the underlying filesystem case - so a.equals(A) is true even when Files.exists(A) is true and Files.exists(a) is false, same for a.toFile().exists() and a.toFile().equals(A.toFile()).